# Why do all software installations from Internet sources involve dragging into Applications?

Tags: macos

I have noticed that installing an application from the Internet in Mac OS always involves dragging an icon into the applications folder.

Why is this so? Couldn't the installer automate this process? Why does the end user have to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those applications that have an installer do do this.  But most don't need an installer, just more complex ones that have to place several files in different locations or make other system changes.  Otherwise, all that's needed is placing the app into wherever you want it.  Sometimes you'll want it in /Applicatons (for all users), sometime in ~/Applications (for your use only), and some people may have some other file structure they prefer.  A single drag or copy would suffice for any of those options.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily - there's also some packages that install [with installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_%28Mac_OS_X%29). The .dmg/drag to applications folder method is more intuitive for simple installs however.